# Finding the maximum possible font size for multiple TextBlocks

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a couple of `TextBlock`s in a Fixed Size Column `Grid`. i.e. The `Grid` size might change, but its column widths are all the same (e.g. 10% of the whole size) and each column contains a `TextBlock`.

The font size of all the `TextBlock`s **MUST** be the same.

How can I find the maximum possible font size which makes all the texts inside `TextBlock`s visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Graphics.MeasureString Method (String, Font, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bt8ty58.aspx) to calculate the fontsize.
Then use some behaviour magic to bind the font size to the TextBlock.

```
private void MeasureStringWidth(PaintEventArgs e)
{

    // Set up string. 
    string measureString = "Measure String";
    Font stringFont = new Font("Arial", 16);

    // Set maximum width of string. 
    int stringWidth = 200;

    // Measure string.
    SizeF stringSize = new SizeF();
    stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(measureString, stringFont, stringWidth);

    // Draw rectangle representing size of string.
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red, 1), 0.0F, 0.0F, stringSize.Width, stringSize.Height);

    // Draw string to screen.
    e.Graphics.DrawString(measureString, stringFont, Brushes.Black, new PointF(0, 0));
}
```